# How to find a string in a string that has one changing character?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to know how I can find a string in another string that has one character that is changing. I've been searching and found out that I have to use regex, but I don't really know how or if I'm doing this right:

The # symbol represents any number (or character, doesn't matter)

```
String original = "1 / #";

original.replaceAll(" / s", "");
```

What would I have to put in for s so it can replace whatever character is there as well? I think I have to put a . that would act as a wildcard, but do I just put it inside my replace string like " / ."?

Edit: By changing I meant that the number won't be static. It'll range from 1-9.

Comment: `.` matches any character besides newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by "is changing"? Are you trying to find a near match? Strings won't oscillate between states somehow.

Comment: explain is changing behavior Please

Answer (score 0):

Almost. You need to reassign the value of `original`, because `replaceAll` doesn't modify the `String` it gets passed.

```
String original = "1 / #";
original = original.replaceAll(" / .", "");
```

Otherwise, your thinking was correct.